# OSX (10.7.5) cloned from HDD to SSD, how can I say it to the OS?

Tags: macos, ssd, clone

I cloned my previous HDD to an SSD with a block-level cloning tool (`dd` :-) ). Now my OS, which was initially installed to a hard disk, now boots and works perfectly from the SSD disk.

But I want to command the OS to use the new features:

- Unused blocks should be deallocated on the hardware level,
- From now it doesn't need to care about the fragmentation.

Can I somehow say it to my osx? How can I test if he knows, that the drive is now an SSD disk?

Comment: You don't need to "tell" your OS. It's not like it fragmented on purpose before and now you need to command it to stop.

Comment: @MC10 Yes, exactly this command is what I want to give it. And I also want to deallocate unused blocks on the hardware level.

Comment: no need to worry about fragment, however if your have a non-apple ssd, you might need to enable trim manually.

Comment: @Chris.C 1) Frag: I agree, but if there is an option to turn off the anti-fragment functionality (as, for example, windows does it on SSDs), I would like to do. 2) Trim: Ok, but _how_ to enable trim manually?

Comment: there is no builtin defrag utility in OSX. And, since OSX 10.7+ has trim support, I assume the OS is "ssd aware" and it should handle these automatically. For trim, https://www.cindori.org/software/trimenabler/. The free version is enough.

Comment: @Chris.C Not surely - as I wrote in my question, I've cloned a HDD. If the trim / notrim information is stored on the disk (as, for example, in both of linux and windows), then it is still disabled.

Comment: TRIM info is stored in `nvram boot-args`, not on the drive itself. Use the cindori app to enable it.